# POST JSON in the URL to WEB API asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I've built a web api in asp.net core, my GET method works perfectly but I'm having trouble with the POST method, I've added a breakpoint in the POST method of my controller and am testing in Postman but the request doesnt even hit my breakpoint, not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**Controller**

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StoreLicenseController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public StoreLicenseController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("terminallicense")]
        public IActionResult GetLicenseByTerminal(Guid storeLicenseId, Guid terminalId)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var terminalLicense = _context.StoreLicenses.FirstOrDefault(t => t.StoreLicenseId == storeLicenseId
                                                                              && t.TerminalId == terminalId);

                if(terminalLicense != null)
                {
                    return Ok(terminalLicense);
                }
                else
                {
                    return NotFound();    
                }
            }
            return NotFound();
        }

                [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] StoreLicenseModel storeLicense)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest("Invalid data");

            using (var sl = _context)
            {
                sl.Add(new StoreLicenseModel()
                {
                    StoreLicenseId = storeLicense.StoreLicenseId,
                    TerminalId = storeLicense.TerminalId,
                    TerminalName = storeLicense.TerminalName,
                    LicenseType = storeLicense.LicenseType,
                    TerminalLicenseDays = storeLicense.TerminalLicenseDays,
                    DateLicensed = storeLicense.DateLicensed,
                    LicenseIsActive = storeLicense.LicenseIsActive,
                });
                sl.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPut("updatelicense")]
        public IActionResult PutStoreLicense(StoreLicenseModel storeLicense)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest("Invalid data");

            using (var sl = _context)
            {
                var existingLicense = sl.StoreLicenses.Where(e => e.StoreLicenseId == storeLicense.StoreLicenseId 
                                                               && e.TerminalId == e.TerminalId).FirstOrDefault();

                if(existingLicense != null)
                {
                    existingLicense.TerminalName = storeLicense.TerminalName;
                    existingLicense.TerminalLicenseDays = storeLicense.TerminalLicenseDays;

                    sl.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

**GET**

https://localhost:44352/api/storelicense/terminallicense?storelicenseid=9A427CE3-EB56-44B0-947D-74DDBD693192&terminalid=B53823EE-ABF1-4370-8ADE-F510E276821C

The get method works fine, but I'm struggling with the below POST method.

**POST**

https://localhost:44352/api/storelicense/newlicense{"StoreLicenseId":"{9A427CE3-EB56-44B0-947D-74DDBD693192}", "TerminalId":"{F9EEBB4E-01BE-4D53-B064-02A73BF689E0}", "TerminalName":"MGRPC", "LicenseType":"NewLicense", "TerminalLicenseDays":"5", "DateLicensed":"2022-10-03 11:29:02 AM", "LicenseIsActive":"True"}

Many thanks

Comment: Why are you posting the json document in the URL instead of as a request body?

Comment: The problem is the invalid URL and the unconventional use of POST, not Web API. The code tried to post to URL `newlicense{"StoreLicenseId"` at port `"{9A427CE3-EB56-44B0-947D-74DDBD693192}...`.

Comment: `GetLicenseByTerminal` works because the action parameters map to query parameters. The same could work with POST if the values were posted as query parameters instead of a single JSON string. The [Model Binding docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sources-1) explains binding works in general, including how to bind parameters to objects or how to change the source that's used with eg `FromQuery` attributes

Comment: Ok, so do i need to add parameters to the POST method ? I've never built an API using POST before, so this is all new to me.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the changed post method, I'v read through some documentation and folowed some samples on [FromBody], I've changed the Postman query with my data in the body, but my breakpoint is still not being hit.

Answer (score 0):

After adding in the `[FromBody]` attribute, I also had to add the following service to the `Program.cs`:

```
"builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();"
```

This fixed up my issues and the `POST` method is now working.